# Где хранится бд которая создана в psql-треминале?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

В каком каталоге хранится бд, которая создана в `psql` терминале через `create database`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psql` - это клиент к `Postgresql` базе данных.

Где, в свою очередь, хранит данные сам `PostgreSQL` можно посмотреть командой:

```
show data_directory;
```

Вот эта вся директория (так же известная как `PGDATA`) - и есть данные СУБД, включая все созданные базы в этом кластере. Обязательно включая абсолютно всё содержимое по всем симлинкам внутри этой директории! Отдельное представление созданной `create datebase` вы найти можете внутри каталога `PGDATA`, но вы обязаны понимать, что без всей целиком директории `PGDATA` отдельные её части -  лишь куча бесполезного бинарного мусора. Для каких-то осмысленных манипуляций с данными `PostgreSQL` обязательно необходим весь `PGDATA` со всем содержимым по всем симлинкам.

Comment: В PGDATA лежат простые файлы. Это и есть бд? Я думал у них будет какое-то расширение.

Comment: Эта директория и есть все данные этого экземпляра postgresql. Расширения файлов? А зачем они нужны? В `PGDATA` за исключением `recovery.conf` (либо пара signal файлов начиная с PG12 вместо него, "спасибо" мне), либо, в некоторых инсталляциях, `pg_hba.conf` и `postgresql.conf` - вообще руками лезть не надо. Ну и зачем усложнять именования бесполезными надуманными расширениями?

Comment: `data_directory` может быть пустая?

Comment: @Hellseher смотря откуда смотреть. По пути из `show data_directory;` - не может. В конфигах такая настройка может отсутствовать.

Answer (score 2):

В терминологии PostgreSQL это называется - кластером, другими словами директория, где будут хранится ВСЕ создаваемые базы данных, это может быть отдельный диск, NFS, DAS, SAN и т.д.

Все возможные конфигурации хранятся в `postgresql.conf` файле:

```
postgres:~$ grep data_directory /etc/postgresql/*/main/postgresql.conf
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main'         # use data in another directory

postgres@:~$ ls -la /var/lib/postgresql/*/main
total 92
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4096 Dec  3 01:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 ..
drwx------  6 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 base
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Dec  1 00:12 global
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_clog
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_commit_ts
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_dynshmem
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_logical
drwx------  4 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_multixact
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Dec  1 00:12 pg_notify
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_replslot
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_serial
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_snapshots
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Dec  1 00:12 pg_stat
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_subtrans
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_tblspc
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_twophase
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres    4 Nov 29 22:43 PG_VERSION
drwx------  3 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 29 22:43 pg_xlog
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   88 Nov 29 22:43 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres  133 Dec  1 00:12 postmaster.opts
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres   91 Dec  1 00:12 postmaster.pid
```

**Ссылки**

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/creating-cluster.html